# onlocationchanged not called in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-location, locationlistener

I'm trying to get current device location using LocationListener method in Android. In some phones it doesn't work or  onlocationchanged is not called. How do I get location in such cases ?
In oncreate :

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 0, this);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

and this

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.e("TAG","lat and long "+latitude+" "+longitude);
}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
```

But onLocationChanged is not called in versions below Marshmallow

Comment: Can you show how you are calling for location updates?

Comment: @PabloBaxter I've updated the code

Comment: And this is on all phones below Marshmallow, or just one?

Comment: @PabloBaxter It worked well in marshamallow phone. Failed in Lollipop devices . I tested in 2 devices

Comment: In your location settings, do you have GPS enabled?

Comment: @PabloBaxter Yes. Have you ever got the same problem ?

Comment: In weird corner cases, where location manager was not working for any updates (Network or GPS), so I had to restart the phone.  The only other time was when I forgot to change location settings from "Wi-Fi and mobile networks" to "High Accuracy" mode, and that only affected GPS.

Comment: @PabloBaxter Thank you for your comment. I hope that Android has solved this issue in Marshamallow

Comment: @RosemolJ have you solved your problem ? i'm getting similar issue like yours

Comment: @TejasPandya I could solve it from the answer given by Manish. It was long before, so I'm not sure whether the same solution will be suite for you or not. Please double check and confirm. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code worked in all devices and tested:

```
 private void getCurrentLocation() {
//        Log.e("getLocation","Called");

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                mlat = location.getLatitude();
                mlon = location.getLongitude();
       String mLogn = Double.toString(mlon);
               String mLatd = Double.toString(mlat);
//                Log.e("mLogn",""+mLogn);
//                Log.e("mLatd",""+mLatd);
                mLogn=mLogn.trim();
                mLatd=mLatd.trim();
                if (mLatd==null || mLogn==null) {
                    if (mLatd.isEmpty()) {
                        mLatd = "No data found";
                    }
                    if (mLogn.isEmpty()) {
                        mLogn = "No data found";
                    }
                }

                // Log.e("Location",""+mlon+" "+mlat);
//                Toast.makeText(CampaignTrain.this, "your location is " + mLogn + " " + mLatd, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };
        String locationProvide = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},COARSE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
                return;
            }


        }
        if ( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
                return;
            }

        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvide, 0, 0, locationListener);
        Location lastLocation=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvide);


    }
```

and set the runtime permission :

```
int FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE=101;
int COARSE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE=102;

     public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode)
            {

               case COARSE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE:
                {
                    if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mLatd="User denied location";
                        mLogn="User denied location";
                    }
                    return;
                }
                case FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE:
                {
                    if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mLatd="User denied location";
                        mLogn="User denied location";
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It returns a location, but onlocationchanged gives me my old location. I need my current location.

Comment: LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)                                                                                                 add this line below                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);